# ExecuteScalar missing Assembly Reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I posted a question about how to save the result of an SQL command to a variable and was told that the execute scalar method should be used, however I can't use it, I'm using the System.Data.SQLClient reference but still not finding it :S

Any ideas???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you really doing:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
....
var command = new SqlCommand();
command.ExecuteScalar();
```

If so. What framework version of .NET are you using?

Answer (score 0):

`SqlClient` has a lowercase `ql`.